# Stuck with simple calculation from form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using a script template to create chunks of code when a user clicks a button, this works fine, but I want to be able to calculate a total within these cloned regions so I have a in-line onBlur statement as follows

```
onblur = "multiply.call(this, this.form.elements.Qty{{ID}}.value, this.form.elements.Cost{{ID}}.value, this.form.elements.Total{{ID}})"
```

As the cloning function updates ID to a value this evaluates to

```
onblur = "multiply.call(this, this.form.elements.Qty1.value, this.form.elements.Cost1.value, this.form.elements.Total1)"
```

My function is

```
function multiply(one, two, three) {
    console.dir(three);
    document.getElementById(three).value = (parseFloat(one) + parseFloat(two)).toFixed(2); // error here
};
```

If I display one and two they have the values from the form, however I get an error writing back to the for of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`.

The console shows the ID of the element three as `Total1`

I think this might be something to do with the jQuery clone and the DOM not being updated. The values are passed OK, but the object might not be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById(three)` returns no match (thus the `undefined`).

You're passing an element to your function `multiply` as parameter `three`, and you're later using it as a string representing the ID of it.

If `three` is verified to be an element, don't call `document.getElementById(three).value` in first place, but directly `three.value`.

Comment: Thanks for this, so simple! (me that is)